# Resource 'corpora/stopwords' not found

Tags: python-3.x, proxy, nltk

I am trying to import stopwords from nltk.corpus. I cannot use nltk.download('stopwords') as I am having proxy issues. I was trying to manually import the stopwords. So this is what I did. I downloaded the nltk_data from github.com and also configured a appropriate path by using nltk.data.path. But when I try top run this code:

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
print(stopwords.words('english'))
```

### I get an error like this.

```
 >Resource 'corpora/stopwords' not found.  Please use the NLTK
 >Downloader to obtain the resource:  >>> nltk.download()
 >Searched in:
 -'C:\\Program Files\\Anaconda3\\Lib\nltk_data'
```

All my nltk data is present at the the above path and also the corpora folder has the stopwords. As I said above I cannot use nltk.download(). Is there anything I am missing out here ?

### Update 1

I reset all the spyder settings and once again ran this code.:

```
    import nltk
    from nltk.corpus import stopwords
    print(stopwords.words('english'))
```

I get an error like :

```
LookupError: 
**********************************************************************
  Resource 'corpora/stopwords' not found.  Please use the NLTK
  Downloader to obtain the resource:  >>> nltk.download()
  Searched in:
    - 'C:\\Users\\586594/nltk_data'
    - 'C:\\nltk_data'
    - 'D:\\nltk_data'
    - 'E:\\nltk_data'
    - 'C:\\Program Files\\Anaconda3\\nltk_data'
    - 'C:\\Program Files\\Anaconda3\\lib\\nltk_data'
    - 'C:\\Users\\586594\\AppData\\Roaming\\nltk_data'
**********************************************************************
```

All my nltk data is present at he "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\nltk_data" and the corpora directory has the stopwords.

Answer (score 6):

I got it fixed by importing nltk and downloading "stopwords" from it.

`import nltk
nltk.download('stopwords')`

Answer (score 2):

You set the `nltk_data` path with a Python command, didn't you? Look carefully at the path in the error message:

> `-'C:\\Program Files\\Anaconda3\\Lib\nltk_data'`

The backslashes between path components are doubled, except for the last one; **you have a literal newline (`\n`) character in your path.** To avoid surprises like this, **always** use raw strings when you write Windows paths. E.g.

```
nltk.data.path.append(r"C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Lib\nltk_data")
```

Comment: I tried doing this. But I am still getting the same lookup error.

Comment: You need to provide more information before anyone can help. Maybe the output of some Windows command that shows the actual path of the file `.../stopwords/english`, and the output of printing `nltk.data.path`. Also, I recommend trying to manually open the file from within Python, using `open()`. See what it thinks of your path.

Comment: I updated my question, please have a look. Basically I want to import stopwords into python without using 'nltk.download()'. Could you please elaborate how exactly can I use the file 'open()' method.

Comment: Is your python script perhaps running from a docker container which doesn't have access to the path you specified?

Comment: I have the SAME issue although none of the above fixes it. i also cannot use the nltk.download function due to work restricting github. i have the files in the directory from a central repository. it just can't see them. i've got zipped and unzipped in the folder. makes no difference. how can i force the filepath? it says it's already looking there in error message but hoping being ecplicit it may work.

Comment: @Mizz, print out the value of `nltk.data.path`, and put your nltk_data hierarchy in one of the standard folders shown there. That way, you will be able to use the data without special to-do. If you can't get this to work, ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same problem and I could resolve it by the following:

```
import nltk
nltk.download('stopwords')
```